# NURLSession batch requests with block. Post parameters changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

```
- (void)someMethodThatIsCalledTwice{

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
            NSString *noteDataString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"album_id=%@&pic_id=%@", albumId,photoId];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSLog(@"PARAMS: %@", noteDataString);
            request.HTTPBody = [noteDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

            NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            }];
}
```

This problem is that if I call this method twice passing different **request.HTTPBody** the **dataTask** gets the the **noteDataString** from the second call for both first and second call.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `albumId` and `photoId` as parameters to `someMethodThatIsCalledTwice:` like,

```
- (void) someMethodThatIsCalledTwiceForAlbumId:(NSString *)albumId photId:(NSString *)pahotId {

     //do the stuff
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work @Akhilrajtr. Is still changing the parameters.. Seems like the NSSURLDataTask block from the first call is executed when the second call was already done and the block is getting parameters from the second call.